# Regular Expression to Exclude Certain Strings in XML

Tags: regex, xml

I have to write a checker which uses regular expressions to exclude things that end with a certain email ending like @tag5.com and @tagfive.com. Not really sure how to do this since I haven't really worked a lot with regular expressions hope someone can show me how or point me in the right direction.

Only need to know what regular expression to use to be more specific.

--**edit**--

nm I found a better solution to the problem I was having and don't have to deal with regular expressions.

Comment: Its a manifest im creating for gmail contextual gadgets. Basically you have to create a regular expression where it searches on the different parts of an email to identify when to display the gadget in each mail.

Comment: I was thinking of this is the correct regular expresion ^(?!.*?@tag5\.com)(?=.*?@tagfive\.com).*?$

Comment: You don't set this up with any concrete information, no examples, no context, nothing.

Comment: If you want help, help us: Show us sample input and output... like a unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the only way to promulgate a negative and positive assertion is something like this:

Regex: `'(?=^(?:(?!@tag5\.com).)*$)(?=.*@tagfive\.com)'`

Target: `'22$sAsWNoid@tag5.comaASDFsdf@tagfive.comasdf!'`

Since, using  `(?!.*@tag5\.com)` will match anything.

```
  (?= ^              # Positive lookahead at start of line
       (?:                # Group
            (?!               # Negative lookahead assertion
                @tag5\.com        # Can't be @tag5.com at this position
            )                 # End assertion
            .                 # This character is ok, take it
       )*                 # End group, do many times until ..
     $               # End of line
  )                  # End of positive lookahead assertion
  (?=                # Meanwhile, back at the start of line, positive lookahead 
     .*                   # Keep going until we find:
     @tagfive\.com        # this (and it MUST be here)
  )                 # End of positive lookahead
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `@tag(5|five)\.com$`